# Can't install "Y" app after migrating google play developer accounts and resetting upload key

Tags: android, upload, google-play, google-play-console

Taking over an application from a previous software provider means that we need to migrate from a "shared" developer account that they used to dedicated developer accounts for every customer. This applies to both App Store and Google Play Store.

For the google play store we are not given the upload key used to sign the app previously. This means that we need to reset the upload key on the google play console. We do this reset according to [instructions provided by google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy=%2Cimportant-considerations-before-requesting-a-key-upgrade%2Crequest-a-key-upgrade-for-all-installs-on-android-n-api-level-and-above). Once the upload keys is reset we successfully upload the app and release it, the issue arises once the app is actually in the store, the previous users can not update the app and are shown the following error dialog. [image: Error message screenshot] The link in this dialog opens the [following](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/14122894?hl=en&error=6003&ctx=ie.flipdish.fd2972&isid=6t4N5w_LQQGV8nT7UmX6QA&visit_id=638367652871262307-1169916459&p=fix_download_install&rd=1).

I am currently completely lost, as we are following google processes, the upload key reset is through the console, the update is pushed and deployed through the console as well. Any issues with the app should have been caught in this process, instead no user is able to update the app. We have spoken to google play support and they have said that this is due to "caches" these caches have not cleared in 6 months for one instance of this.

Comment: @derpirscher we are using google play app signing. Yes we create an aab locally using the upload key that was sent to google. In the google console there is a section called: "Request upload key reset" with the subtitle: "To start using a new upload certificate, request an upload key reset".

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer, you may have already encountered such behavior. If you debug your application, you install it onto the device signed with the Android debug key distributed along with the SDK and then when you try to install the same app with the release key you receive the same error message as in your case.

It happens because if there is already an installed app with the specific package name, Android OS considers installing another app with the same package name as an update to the existing one. The signing is a security feature that tells Android that two apps with the same package name can substitute one another.

If two apps have the same package name, Android OS can handle this situation in two ways:

1. When the signing key is the same - the app you installed the latest will substitute the app that was installed previously(the versionCode should be higher though). But the key is not supposed to be unique - you can have an unlimited number of apps installed using the same signing key - the only uniqueness condition is the different package name.
2. When the signing key is different, the Android OS will always give an error, and you won't be able to install the app with the same package and different signing key if you already have one application with this package name installed. You cannot influence it, you cannot change it - it is just how the Android OS works.

Maybe there are some custom ROMs that allow such a behavior, but even if there are - they won't be google certified; hence - no google services.

More info in the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module), [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing), and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

So the conclusion here - Android OS won't update the old version of the app that are already installed under the old signing key with your new version with the new signing key even with the same package name. And there is nothing we can do about it. We can either restore the old key from the old app provider or, to allow old users to reinstall the app, change the package name(`applicationId` in build gradle file).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. Before updating an app with the package id `com.foobar.app` the Android system checks if an app with that package id is already installed and if yes if the installed version and the new version are signed with the same *app signing key*. If yes, the update is allowed, if no the update is declined.

This is a security measure to prevent any app being replaced by a malicious counterfeit. Because otherwise anybody could create an app with the package id `com.foobar.app`, sign it with an arbitrary key and trick the users into installing that malicious app.

First of all, as you said you are using Play App Signing you have to understand the difference between an *upload key*  and an *app signing key*.

- The *upload key* is stored at your local machine and you use it to sign the AAB you are uploading to the playstore. During upload the playstore verifies, the correct upload key is used to sign the AAB. It will reject the AAB if any other key was used.
- After the AAB is uploaded, the playstore creates an APK from your AAB and signs it with the *app signing key*, which is stored in a secure place at google. The app signing key can either be generated by the playstore or you can upload a key you generated locally to the play store. The latter is especially important for apps that were released before Play App Signing was available, so the developers can upload their signing key to the playstore when they switch to Play App Signing.

So now that you have adopted that app and transferred it into your account, you probably (intentionally or unintentionally - I never did such a transfer so I don't know what happens during this process) created a new app signing key for that app in your account. Thus when you create a new release, it's signed with a new key and thus all existing installations will refuse to update.

You requesting a new *upload key* doesn't change anything in this situation. Because that upload key is only used to verify the AAB you are uploading to the play store and doesn't have anything to do with the final APK, which is still signed by the same *app signing key* stored in google playstore.

There are two things you can do now

1. If you can get hold of the **original** *app signing key*, you can upload it to the play store. Once you have done this, the play store will use that key to sign the APK and updates will be possible again.
2. If you can't get hold of the original key, you could try to request an upgrade of your app signing key as described in the [docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756). If that is successful, at least devices with API Level 24 (N) and above will then be able to install updates again ...